(GCP-Cloud build)Docker: COPY failed: file not found in build context (Dockerfile)
I am currently struggling with COPY instruction in Dockerfile.
Step #0: Installing collected packages: tbb, python-decouple, intel-openmp, urllib3, tzdata, typing_extensions, tqdm, threadpoolctl, sqlparse, six, safetensors, regex, PyYAML, PyJWT, psycopg2-binary, pillow, packaging, networkx, MarkupSafe, joblib, idna, fsspec, filelock, django-widget-tweaks, colorama, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, python-dateutil, Jinja2, gunicorn, asgiref, huggingface-hub, Django, tokenizers, djangorestframework, djangorestframework-simplejwt
Step #0: Successfully installed Django-5.0.6 Jinja2-3.1.4 MarkupSafe-2.1.5 PyJWT-2.8.0 PyYAML-6.0.1 asgiref-3.8.1 certifi-2024.7.4 charset-normalizer-3.3.2 colorama-0.4.6 django-widget-tweaks-1.5.0 djangorestframework-3.15.2 djangorestframework-simplejwt-5.3.1 filelock-3.15.4 fsspec-2024.6.1 gunicorn-22.0.0 huggingface-hub-0.24.3 idna-3.7 intel-openmp-2021.4.0 joblib-1.4.2 networkx-3.3 packaging-24.1 pillow-10.4.0 psycopg2-binary-2.9.9 python-dateutil-2.9.0.post0 python-decouple-3.8 regex-2024.5.15 requests-2.32.3 safetensors-0.4.3 six-1.16.0 sqlparse-0.5.0 tbb-2021.13.0 threadpoolctl-3.5.0 tokenizers-0.19.1 tqdm-4.66.4 typing_extensions-4.12.2 tzdata-2024.1 urllib3-2.2.2
Step #0: WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Step #0: 
Step #0: [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.2
Step #0: [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Step #0: Removing intermediate container 3fe3c845384e
Step #0:  ---> e229e4e549e4
Step #0: Step 5/8 : COPY . /app/
Step #0:  ---> bbd7f8e842ba
Step #0: Step 6/8 : COPY .env .env
Step #0: COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat .env: file does not exist
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

I have not excluded in .dockerignore
How can I do it?
File .env is stored in the same dir as Dockerfile.
i dont no
Dockerfile
# 베이스 이미지 설정
FROM python:3.10-slim

# 작업 디렉토리 설정
WORKDIR /app

# 필요한 파일들을 작업 디렉토리로 복사
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app/

COPY .env .env

# 장고의 static 파일을 모음
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# 장고 애플리케이션을 시작
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "config.wsgi:application"]


Please update your question to include (a) the command you're using (perhaps gcloud builds submit ${PWD} --tag=... --project=...?); (b) proof that your local folder includes .env (perhaps ls -la)

I'm able to repro your error by creating e.g. .gcloudignore (another ignore file) used by gcloud to inhibit file copies.
